# Replace unknown string using sed in bash script

Tags: text-processing

Let's say I have a `wp-config.php` like so:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'db_name');
define('DB_USER', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');
```

In my bash script I have a construct similar to:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Database config
echo -e "\ndatabase name: \c"
read DB_NAME
sed -i -e "s/define('DB_NAME', );/define('DB_NAME', $DB_NAME);/g" "C:/Apache24/htdocs/test.txt"
```

It doesn't work however. How could I edit (using `sed`) the variables `db_name`, `user` & `pass` in `test.txt` given that these variables would typically be unknown in advance?

Comment: Have you considered using `m4` instead of `sed`?  See `man m4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eval "`echo 'NL=qsq' | tr 'qs' '\047\012'`"; # newline
echo DB_NAME; read DB_NAME;
db_name_esc=$DB_NAME
db_name_esc=${db_name_esc//\\/\\\\\\\\}   # escape backslash
db_name_esc=${db_name_esc//\'/\\\\\'}     # escape single quote
db_name_esc=${db_name_esc//\"/\\\"}       # escape double quote
db_name_esc=${db_name_esc//&/\\&}         # escape & special to sed
db_name_esc=${db_name_esc//\//\\\/}       # escape / special to s///
db_name_esc=${db_name_esc//${NL}/\\${NL}} # esc literal newline for sed

# and then plug in your variables properly escaped for both PHP+sed
sed -e "
   s/\\(define('DB_NAME',\\).*/\\1 '$db_name_esc');/
" yourfile
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. Use `-i` flag to edit the actual file :).